# Eclipse on Ubuntu 10 java-6-openjdk has missing jar's

Tags: java, compiling, eclipse

Out of the blue, my eclipse is reporting missing jars in my Java Build Path.

```
netx.jar
gnome-java-bridge.jar
plugin.jar
```

I wonder what I did wrong ? Was it a upgrade that messed it up ?

I am unable remove those jar's from my the list aswell (that is probably because my eclipse is not running as super user).

Just running as super user, removing those missing jar's may not be the solution. Any advice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem after an upgrade i was missing the 
gnome-java-bridge.jar
in my open-1.6-jdk

I changed all my projects to the 1.7 openjdk.
since everthing is working as it should!

Comment: Ok, I see it now. Thanks.. I'll change to 1.7 and report back.

Comment: Although moving to 1.7 is not the right solution as for many people who read this q&a, they may need to do a full round of testing for a new JDK. I recommend trying what Rick recommended, or my magic (answered below).

Answer (score 3):

I also had the exact same problem as Jerry. Missing my gnome-java-bridge.jar. However, you don't have to load the new jdk. Just reselect the jre and Eclipse will reload the library list from the jre and everything works as expected

`Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs`

You might have to edit your Runtime for your Server settings (I did).

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem without installing the jdk 1.7.
The problem was due to the value 1.5 set in the field "Compiler Compliance level" at  Window->Preferences->Java->Compiler.

Having jdk 1.6 and changing the value to 1.6, the problem was solved.

Cheers,
 Eric.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to update the solution.

I installed JDK 1.7, created my eclipse setup to work with 1.7, and magically 1.6 too works now. May be I should have tried what Rick did. I will next time around.